# Convert Inno Setup Pascal Script TColor to HTML hex colour

Tags: hex, inno-setup, pascalscript

Inno Setup Pascal Script has colour variables like `clBtnFace`, `clYellow` in Delphi.

I like to know how can I convert any of those `TColor` to HTML hex colour.

*For example, if I convert `clBtnFace` to a HTML hex colour, the result should be `#497AC2`. And if I convert `clYellow` to a HTML hex colour, the result should be `#FFFF00`.*

I found many examples for above, but they're for RGB colours. I want to convert `TColor` to **HTML hex colour** to use as hex colour in the command line parameters for ImageMagick in my Pascal Script like `...xc:#497AC2...`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```pascal
function ColorToWebColorStr(Color: TColor): string;
var
  RGB: Integer;
begin
  RGB := ColorToRGB(Color);
  Result :=
    Format('#%.2x%.2x%.2x', [Byte(RGB), Byte(RGB shr 8), Byte(RGB shr 16)]);
  Result := UpperCase(Result);
end;
```

For the `ColorToRGB`, see [Converting Inno Setup WizardForm.Color to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30986658/850848).

---

*Though note that using this with system colors (`clXXX` constants) has little sense on modern themed versions of Windows. For example `clBtnFace` will always return a system color. Which has nothing to do with an actual color of the form. Each form can have a different color/skin. The `clBtnFace` is always the same. Actually even with the system skin/theme, the actual form color is a different shade of gray than `clBtnFace` on modern versions of Windows. The actual form color is `clBtnFace` only, if you turn off themes in Windows (i.e. with the classical Windows 2000 look).*

Answer (score -1):

Here's another method to do it:

```
function TColorToHex(aColor: TColor): String;
begin
  var RGB := ColorToRGB(aColor);
  Result := '#' +
            Byte(RGB).ToHexString +
            Byte(RGB shr 8).ToHexString +
            Byte(RGB shr 16).ToHexString;
end;
```

Comment: This won't even compile (might work in Delphi, but this question is about Inno Setup/Pascal Script).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Why would it not work? Due to the inline variable? Or what?

Comment: So you didn't even try it, right? There are no "helper methods" in Inno Setup/Pascal Script. So there's nothing like `Byte.ToHexString`.

Answer (score -1):

Quite easy to understand function :-)

```
function PasColor2WebColor(C: integer): string;
var
  r, g, b: byte;
begin
  c:= ColorToRGB(C);
  r:= GetRValue(c);
  g:= GetGValue(c);
  b:= GetBValue(c);
  result:= Format('#%s%s%s', [IntToHex(r, 2), IntToHex(g, 2), 
                              IntToHex(b, 2)]);
end;//  PasColor2WebColor
```

Comment: The same as with the answer by @Martin Kakhuis: This won't even compile – might work in Delphi, but this question is about Inno Setup/Pascal Script – There are no `GetXValue` functions in Inno Setup.