# Convert HTML hex colour to TColor in Inno Setup Pascal Script

Tags: html, inno-setup, pascalscript, tcolor

I want to convert a HTML Hex colour to a `TColor` in Inno Setup Pascal Script.

I tried reversing the function `ColorToWebColorStr` from [Convert Inno Setup Pascal Script TColor to HTML hex colour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39009484/850848), but I might need a function like `RGBToColor` to get result as the `TColor`.

Example: *Conversion of `#497AC2` HTML Hex Colour should be returned as `TColor` `$C27A49`.*
*Input should be a HTML colour string representation and output should be a `TColor`.*

When I use the following function from VCL `Windows` unit in Inno Setup, `TForm.Color` shows as red.

```pascal
const
  COLORREF: TColor;

function RGB( R, G, B: Byte): COLORREF;
begin
  Result := (R or (G shl 8) or (B shl 16));
end;

DataChecker.Color := RGB( 73, 122, 194);
```

*The colour I expected in `TForm.Color` is:*

```html
<html>
<body bgcolor="#497AC2">
<h2>This Background Colour is the Colour I expected instead of Red.</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

*Additionally, I also like to know why red colour is returning here (form showing red) instead of expected semi light blue.........*

---

*I want to use the conversion as:*

```pascal
#define BackgroundColour "#497AC2"

procedure InitializeDataChecker;
...
begin
...
  repeat
    ShellExec('Open', ExpandConstant('{pf64}\ImageMagick-7.0.2-Q16\Convert.exe'),
      ExpandConstant('-size ' + ScreenResolution + ' xc:' '{#BackgroundColour}' + ' -quality 100% "{tmp}\'+IntToStr(ImageNumber)+'-X.jpg"'), '', SW_HIDEX, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode); 
...    
  until FileExists(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\'+IntToStr(ImageNumber)+'.jpg')) = False; 
...
end;

...
DataChecker := TForm.Create(nil);
{ ---HERE IT SHOULD BE RETURNED AS `$C27A49`--- }
DataChecker.Color := NewFunction({#BackgroundColour})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```pascal
function RGB(r, g, b: Byte): TColor;
begin
  Result := (Integer(r) or (Integer(g) shl 8) or (Integer(b) shl 16));
end;

function WebColorStrToColor(WebColor: string): TColor;
begin
  if (Length(WebColor) <> 7) or (WebColor[1] <> '#') then
    RaiseException('Invalid web color string');

  Result :=
    RGB(
      StrToInt('$' + Copy(WebColor, 2, 2)),
      StrToInt('$' + Copy(WebColor, 4, 2)),
      StrToInt('$' + Copy(WebColor, 6, 2)));
end;
```

---

Your RGB function does not work because it seems that Pascal Script (contrary to Delphi) does not implicitly convert/expand the `Byte` to the `Integer` for the `shl` operation. So you have to do it explicitly.